# AngularJS - Hide div when list is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I currently have the following :

```
<div class="row">
<!-- Banners -->
<h2 class="mt15">Banners</h2>
<div class="col-sm-3 ml5 mt5" ng-repeat="banner in banners" ng-if="!banner.public">
    <ul class="rdopts form-group">
        <li class="rdopt opt mb10">
            <label class="btn btn-danger btn-sm w100pc">
                <input type="radio" name="banner_option" autocomplete="off" ng-model="vm.editModel.banner" value="{{banner.file}}" ng-checked="{{banner.file === main_image_css_file}}">{{banner.name}}
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Currently, I have both **public** and **private** banners in the banner list. The `banner.public` property does this distinction. What I currently need to do is hide the whole div when I don't have any element on the list, given that the list only shows the banners that respect the `ng-if="!banner.public"` condition?

Any idea on how can I do this using Angular?

Clarification: What I want to do is to hide the whole row div when I don't have any element on the list that fills the ng-if="!banner.public" condition.

Comment: `ng-if="banner"` try this one.

Comment: I will provide a solution in few minutes.

Comment: Check out my down-voted answer, added an update. Use ng-if on the row div

Comment: @ClaudioRibeiro, It is working ?

Comment: Still making some tests. Will approve when everything is good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use  `filter` method for your `list`.

```
<div class="row" ng-if="verify()">
<!-- Banners -->
<h2 class="mt15">Banners</h2>
<div class="col-sm-3 ml5 mt5" ng-repeat="banner in banners" ng-if="!banner.public">
  <ul class="rdopts form-group">
    <li class="rdopt opt mb10">
        <label class="btn btn-danger btn-sm w100pc">
            <input type="radio" name="banner_option" autocomplete="off" ng-model="vm.editModel.banner" value="{{banner.file}}" ng-checked="{{banner.file === main_image_css_file}}">{{banner.name}}
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.verify=function(){
    var result=$scope.banners.filter(function(banner){
            return banner.public;    
    });
    return result.length!=0;
};
```

Comment: Why can't you do the same with `ng-if`?

Comment: I would always recommend ng-if, as it does not render the HTML in the view.

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that is still shows the h2 above it. I want to hide the whole "row" div.

Comment: @CláudioRibeiro, i edited my answer. Please take a look now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-sm-3 ml5 mt5" ng-repeat="banner in banners" ng-hide="banner.public.length == 0">
<ul class="rdopts form-group">
    <li class="rdopt opt mb10">
        <label class="btn btn-danger btn-sm w100pc">
            <input type="radio" name="banner_option" autocomplete="off" ng-model="vm.editModel.banner" value="{{banner.file}}" ng-checked="{{banner.file === main_image_css_file}}">{{banner.name}}
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

you can use `ng-hide` or `ng-show`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 ml5 mt5" ng-repeat="banner in banners" ng-if="banner.public.length!=0">
<ul class="rdopts form-group">
    <li class="rdopt opt mb10">
        <label class="btn btn-danger btn-sm w100pc">
            <input type="radio" name="banner_option" autocomplete="off" ng-model="vm.editModel.banner" value="{{banner.file}}" ng-checked="{{banner.file === main_image_css_file}}">{{banner.name}}
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

`ng-if` is appropriate in this case as it will not render the HTML in the view i.e, you cannot see the HTML during inspect element.

Comment: ng-if is what i will recommend to use as it is cleaner that ng-show or ng-hide.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check the length of the array with `ng-if='banner.public.length'`, if that is available then that will be attached to the DOM otherwise it will be detached:

```js
var app = angular.module('demoapp',[]);
app.controller('demoCtrl', function($scope){
   $scope.banners = [{"public":[]}];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='demoapp'>
  <div ng-controller='demoCtrl'>
    demoapp
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat='banner in banners' ng-if='banner.public.length'>{{banner.public}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

From what I gather, you have a single list of banners. A banner can either be public or private. Depending on how you are representing **banner** in your controller. Try the following:

Assuming banners as:

```
$scope.banners = [{public: true}, {public: false}];
```

You can have a function in your controller as:

```
$scope.hasPublic = (banners) => {
    var hasPublic = false;
    banners.forEach((banner) => {
        if (banner.public === true) hasPublic = true;
    });
    return hasPublic;
}

<div class="row" ng-if="hasPublic(banners)">
    <h2 class="mt15">Banners</h2>
    <div class="col-sm-3 ml5 mt5" ng-repeat="banner in banners" ng-if="banner.public">
        <!--- Rest of the code here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using both ng-if and ng-show together. What is the sense?

Comment: review your answer before posting.